# How to dismiss the parent custom dialog when clicking Ok on the second dialog

Tags: android, dialog, android-alertdialog

I am showing two dialogs each should be displayed with different network call on the same activity (Login Activity). In which if I click on "Resend Email" text view in the first dialog then I am having another network call that shows me another dialog. When I click "OK" on the second dialog, it is dismissed. But the first one is still shown. So how to dismiss both when I click "Ok" on the second.

Answer (score 0):

create a local `Dialog` variable `dialogOne` and when you click on ok of the dialog two dismiss both

```
   btn_ok.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        isShown = true;
        dialog.dismiss();
        dialogOne.dismiss();
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Dismiss both dialog when button clicked and before dismiss must check dialog is visible or not to avoid nullpointer exception.

```
btn_ok.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        if(dialog.isShowing())
        dialog.dismiss();
        if(firstdialog.isShowing())
        firstdialog.dismiss();
    }
});
```